# Any custom control for input fields?

Tags: custom-controls, abap, input-field, dynpro

Is there any control container for input fields? I have a splitter container with a two cells. In the first cell is a tree control and after double click on some node i want to show input fields in the second cell, for this node.

Answer (score 3):

There is no control container for screens (dynpros) that can be recommended fpr everyday use. You basically have two options:

You could use a control to emulate an input screen. This might be a dynamic document (see reports `DD_*`) or an ALV control. From my experience, this can quickly turn into a lot of work and a long-term maintenance nightmare because you have to bend some of the dialog processing logic almost to its breaking point.

The other - and more common - option is to use a screen for the detail data and attach the tree as a docking container. This is the way that `SE80` and similar transactions work. The user might perceive it as a master (tree) / detail (screen) view, but technically it's a detail (screen) + navigation (tree) implementation.